# In Vertica SQL, what does "pipe forward-slash" mean: "|/"?

Tags: sql, vertica

I was reading some old code at work, and I ran into this:

```
SELECT
    0.003*spins + 0.291*(|/spins)  as 'cheat_score' 
FROM 
    spin_table;
```

What does `|/` mean? The characters are a pipe (or vertical bar) followed by a forward slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://my.vertica.com/docs/7.1.x/HTML/Content/Authoring/SQLReferenceManual/LanguageElements/Operators/MathematicalOperators.htm says `|/` is the square root operator (so e.g. `|/ 25` is `5`).